# Error after installing Node.js in Linux

Tags: node.js, ubuntu-14.04, mean-stack

I am getting following error after typing **$ node - version** in My Linux Machine:

```
Error: unrecognized flag -
Try --help for options

module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module '/home/ojas/version'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:935:3
```

I have used following Commands  while Installing:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
$ curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup | sudo bash -
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things to point out:
- The executable is called `nodejs` and not `node`, in Ubuntu.
- The flag is `--version`

```
~$ nodejs --version  
v0.10.25
```

Comment: Can you Please tell procedure or redirect me to site from where i can install MEAN stack on my ubuntu machine

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-a-mean-js-stack-on-an-ubuntu-14-04-server